# Replace with regular expression (leave middle text)

Tags: regex, replace, phpstorm

I have a site where I need to replace almost 400 of these kind of strings (across dozens or hundreds of files)

```
$_POST['some_text_here']
```

with this

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['some_text_here'])
```

**The key here is that I want to add the ending parenthesis as well or otherwise this would be a trivial search and replace.**

I am new to regular expressions so I dont even know if a search and replace is possible while leaving text (specifically the 'some_text_here') in the middle of the replace.

I am using PHPStorm for this if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet as I am not sure if this is even possible with regex search and replace.

Comment: Then first try out something. Sure this is possible. But you need to give it some try first to get to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```regex
(\$_POST\['[^']*'\])
```

Then replace with something like this

```regex
mysql_real_escape_string($1)
```

Code:

```php
preg_replace ( '($_POST\\[\'[^\']\'\\])', 'mysql_real_escape_string($1)', 'file contents go here' )
```

*Not tested*

Comment: Great thank you.  I actually modified it slightly.  I added what I used below

Comment: (\$_POST\[.*\])  //I added a slash at the beginning and changed to a wildcard inside the POST text.

Comment: Ah... yes. I forgot the star. I will edit the original answer. Also forgot to escape the `$`. Just realize that `.*` is potentially dangerous if you have multiple `$_POST[]` statements on the same line.

Comment: Yes the .* matched up two $_POST statements for me so I believe your implementation is better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, regex isn't what you want.. you rather want something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

RegEx..

```
\$_POST\['([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'\]
```

Replace - something like this:

```
mysql_real_escape_string\(\$_POST\['$1'\]\)
```

Btw: mysql_* is deprecated and shouldn't used anymore - use mysqli_ or PDO instead

Comment: I am looking to do a search and replace across dozens to hundreds of *files*, not a group of POST data variables otherwise this is a good way to loop through all of them.

Comment: You never mentioned some files.. We have no crystal ball

Comment: Oh... I see.. you have sql injection problems and want to handle this with a simple search and replace. You can still use my code - just add it in the first lines of your files - but i suggest you to replace every mysql_* function with it's equivalent PDO function to handle this behavior better.

Comment: Yes, I inherited this site and want to put that in place ASAP.